# How to copy a database to another server with only some of the rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, azure-data-studio

Trying to copy a database from a hosted server to a local server for testing purposes and am trying to avoid exporting the whole database as a .bacpac file as there are some tables with tens, maybe hundreds of thousands of rows.

I've tried looking for ways to export the database as a .bacpac file using only the top X rows of each database without luck. I have similarly had little luck with exporting the database as a .dacpac file and then transferring a select amount of data between the hosted and local servers.

Comment: BACPAC will only copy the schema and data or the tables that you select in the wizard. For your need, there is no straight solution, you need to export only the schema via Generate scripts, after that select top 10 or 100 records from each of your table, and then use `BCP` utility to get imported into your new db.

Comment: Shame, I was afraid of that. Also not sure why I got a downvote.